# How to trigger mouse-over in Android

Tags: browser

I visit sites where some features like pop-up menus and tooltips are invoked by placing the mouse cursor over an item. I would like to use all the features while using my Android tablet. So, I'm looking for a way to simulate the mouse-over event in Android browser, especially in Android 4.1.2

Comment: I really wish there was an answer to this that worked with tool tips — otherwise some sites are really frustrating with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long-click is basically the same as a right-click which brings up context menus.

Things for mouse-over such as viewing titles, and link urls can be accomplished with bookmarklets.  I have examples bookmarklets to view all titles, and all href links, see "href:", "href-x:" and "parentips" on for instance  my [dolphin gestures](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/dolphin/dolphin_gestures.htm) page.
You can invoke example by clicking on one of those boxed bookmarklets links.

To learn more about bookmarklets, if you are not familiar with them, I would suggest starting at http://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets.

Comment: I see you assume I have installed Dolphin. Maybe I will if there is no other way. I wonder if Android addresses the problem somehow without installing third-party browsers

Comment: You can   implement boolmarklets  in any browser that has bookmarks and has Javascript withoutpt enabled.   I prefer Dolphin because gestures can be used to invoke a bookmark without using a keyboard.  I use boolmarklets in the default browser that comes with Android Gingerbread 2.3.4.     A big problem with Android is not havingreal scrollbars and why I am not using hundreds of bookmarkets on Android.    Click on the bookmarklets on the page I referenced and you will see they work in your browser.

Comment: This does not sound as though it works with tool tips (text displayed on mouseover) — or does it?

Answer (score 4):

Long-press the item (to open its context-menu), then hit the "back" key (to leave the menu). Works on most devices. Explained e.g. [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/help.php?topic=applists), scroll down to "Smartphones".

Comment: Long-press does not activate any menu. It starts text selection

Comment: Then you're not long-pressing on a link. I didn't check all combinations of mouseOver events, admitted. But when it starts text-selection, what happens then when you press "back"? Is the mouseOver executed or not?

Answer (score 1):

Going necro on this since it was the most relevant thread I found when searching for a solution to this issue.

Based on the answer from @dmcritchie, I found the following works quite well to see tooltips when using Chrome on Android, which you'd normally only be able to see on mouse-over/hover when using Chrome on a laptop/desktop (Mac or PC).

1. When viewing this page on Chrome (Android app), open the menu, press ☆ to bookmark the page, then click "edit" on the notification that appears at the bottom of the screen to edit the bookmark.
2. Copy/paste the following to replace the name of the bookmark: **πParenTips: Turns tooltips (title attributes) into parenthetical phrases. (https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/sitespecific.html#paren_tips)**
3. Copy/paste the following to replace the URL of the bookmark:

```
javascript:(function(){ var z=[],N,title,tc,j; function r(N) { if (N.title) z.push(N); var C=N.childNodes,i;for(i=0;i<C.length;++i)r(C[i]); } r(document.body); for (j in z) { N=z[j]; title=document.createTextNode("("+N.title+")"); tc=document.createElement("span"); tc.style.color="green"; tc.style.background="black"; tc.appendChild(title); N.parentNode.insertBefore(tc,N.nextSibling); N.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(" "),tc); }})();
```

4. Hit the left arrow ← at the top to finish editing the bookmark.
5. The next time you're viewing a page in Chrome on your Android device and want to see all of the tooltips that you'd normally only be able to see on mouse-over when using a desktop browser, click in the address bar, type πParenTips (case insensitive), and click the bookmark you just saved/edited (it should show a ☆ before it). The javascript saved as the URL of the bookmark will reveal the tooltips in parentheses after every object on the page that has one.

If you want to take this a step further (which I did), you can and the javascript into a macro, and add it into the MacroDroid drawer. Then, rather than needing to remember the name of the bookmark, you can just slide open the drawer and click the macro to execute the functionality.

Here's the code for the macro. If you use MacroDroid and want to import it, just save this using a text editor as `ParenTips(tooltips).macro`.

```
{"localVariables":[],"m_GUID":-7639397451296706360,"m_actionList":[{"m_option":1,"swipeAreaColour":0,"swipeAreaHeight":45,"swipeAreaOpacity":50,"swipeAreaOption":0,"swipeAreaVerticalOffset":50,"swipeAreaVisibleWidth":10,"swipeAreaWidth":10,"m_SIGUID":-7094001615827768492,"m_classType":"MacroDroidDrawerAction","m_constraintList":[],"m_isDisabled":false,"m_isOrCondition":false},{"m_delayInMilliSeconds":500,"m_delayInSeconds":0,"m_useAlarm":false,"m_SIGUID":-8018690266470723056,"m_classType":"PauseAction","m_constraintList":[],"m_isDisabled":false,"m_isOrCondition":false},{"action":0,"uiInteractionConfiguration":{"clickOption":2,"contentDescription":"","longClick":false,"xyPoint":{"x":300,"y":220},"type":"Click"},"m_SIGUID":-7967589745354417308,"m_classType":"UIInteractionAction","m_constraintList":[],"m_isDisabled":false,"m_isOrCondition":false},{"m_delayInMilliSeconds":500,"m_delayInSeconds":0,"m_useAlarm":false,"m_SIGUID":-8261751054593356492,"m_classType":"PauseAction","m_constraintList":[],"m_isDisabled":false,"m_isOrCondition":false},{"action":4,"uiInteractionConfiguration":{"forceClear":false,"text":"javascript:(function(){ var z\u003d[],N,title,tc,j; function r(N) { if (N.title) z.push(N); var C\u003dN.childNodes,i;for(i\u003d0;i\u003cC.length;++i)r(C[i]); } r(document.body); for (j in z) { N\u003dz[j]; title\u003ddocument.createTextNode(\"(\"+N.title+\")\"); tc\u003ddocument.createElement(\"span\"); tc.style.color\u003d\"green\"; tc.style.background\u003d\"black\"; tc.appendChild(title); N.parentNode.insertBefore(tc,N.nextSibling); N.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(\" \"),tc); }})();\n","useClipboard":false,"type":"Paste"},"m_SIGUID":-5907160346063321222,"m_classType":"UIInteractionAction","m_constraintList":[],"m_isDisabled":false,"m_isOrCondition":false},{"m_delayInMilliSeconds":500,"m_delayInSeconds":0,"m_useAlarm":false,"m_SIGUID":-7595853986867803473,"m_classType":"PauseAction","m_constraintList":[],"m_isDisabled":false,"m_isOrCondition":false},{"action":0,"uiInteractionConfiguration":{"clickOption":2,"contentDescription":"","longClick":false,"xyPoint":{"x":980,"y":2100},"type":"Click"},"m_SIGUID":-4895727888846778703,"m_classType":"UIInteractionAction","m_constraintList":[],"m_isDisabled":false,"m_isOrCondition":false}],"m_category":"Bookmarklets","m_constraintList":[],"m_description":"Turns tooltips (title attributes) into parenthetical phrases. Details:\nhttps://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/sitespecific.html#paren_tips","m_descriptionOpen":true,"m_enabled":true,"m_excludeLog":false,"m_headingColor":0,"m_isOrCondition":false,"m_name":"ParenTips(tooltips)","m_triggerList":[{"fakeIcon":2131231023,"m_SIGUID":-8670230100873968551,"m_classType":"EmptyTrigger","m_constraintList":[],"m_isDisabled":false,"m_isOrCondition":false}]}
```

If it doesn't seem to work on your device, you may just need to edit the coordinates for the `UI Interaction(Click [x,y])` actions: (first one) to click the address bar in Chrome, and (second one) to click the enter/go key on your phone's keyboard.

Lastly, if you want to get rid of the parenthesized tooltips, just reload the page.